# Is having to do repetitive work all day a sign that my organization is under-staffed?

Tags: management, people-management

Is having to do repetitive work all day a sign that my organization is under-staffed?

I have an advanced degree and my job is basically pressing the same 12 buttons repeatedly all day and writing basic e-mails, tallying files, counting files, data-entry, data-formatting.
My jobs is a like a really bad videogame after I realized it's best done with a video game controller/joystick.

I've become more productive by thinking outside the box and mapping the 12 buttons to a game-controller and using a video game controller to do the data-entry/file organization on my job or transferring numbers/names from one file to another.

I can't code a program to automate my job because there's also arbitrary rules for reformatting tables and not well-defined input and output spaces so there'd be too many rules to read and output files.

If someone made a heat-map of the buttons I press all day, it'd be 90% click and drag, command + V.

Aside:

My boss complains that I'm not a fan of pressing 12 buttons all day and thinks I probably work for three hours or four hours a day and then spend the other time doing my own stuff.

I think my boss should hire 5 low-wage high schoolers to do data entry rather than hire 1 person to do data-entry.

My boss also insists that yelling at him and debating with him is a form of learning. My boss is cool if I yell at him. I spend 2% of the time arguing with my boss because he expects me to read his mind and he realized I can't read his mind. The so-called learning is just him winning a debate on what the definition of XYZ is. Having to yell at someone for 30 minutes and lose a debate is not a "learning" process. Fighting is not a learning process. He thinks the high-light of my job is him yelling at me and showing me a webpage with supports his propositions and thinks that's more intellectual than a harvard math professor's lecture.

Comment: Is this the same family business in your last question? Yelling at the boss for half an hour would get you terminated in many places.

Comment: "**My boss also insists that yelling at him and debating with him is a form of learning. My boss is cool if I yell at him.**" -  Is this whole paragraph serious ? Are you sure you are not being humorous or sarcastic in this last paragraph ? - For all other young people who just join the workforce, never yell at your boss, and be very careful, respectful, and professional when you "debate with your boss", or else, "**You are fired**".

Comment: Yelling at your boss or at anyone will be harmful to your own mental health in the long run, and will also raise your blood pressure a few times per day, which is bad for your physical health.

Comment: These are valid points, What if I cannot find another job?

Comment: Do you apply for other jobs ? If yes, do you "**yell at and debate with the interviewers**" that you are the best candidate for the jobs ? - No, I am just kidding about the "**yell and debate**" thing :-)  Seriously, have you applied for jobs at LinkedIn, and other job websites ? In addition, there are also staffing and recruiting companies...

Comment: @Germania this is the best time to be job seeking in my entire lifetime.  Employers are begging for employees.

Answer (score 5):

An indication of understaffing would be that the work cannot get done given the current number of employees working normal hours. What you have described is simply a bad fit. If you have an advanced degree, you should not be doing data entry except on a very limited basis. If you don't work well with your boss, it's even more a bad fit. You should talk to your boss about redefining your role; you've already shown innovation that could improve others' productivity. If that does not work, you should start looking elsewhere (and don't wait to get started).